# What part of speech is "rested" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, parts-of-speech, past-participles

In the sentence, "I was well rested," is *rested* an adjective or a past participle?

Similarly, in the sentence, "Your room was organized," is *organized* an adjective or a past participle?

Comment: What syntactic tests have you attempted?

Comment: For **organized** [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/organized) and [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/organized) both say "adjective". How hard was that?

Comment: "Well-rested" is a verb-centred compound adjective with the past participle **verb** "rested" as head. In "Your room was organised", "organised" is ambiguous. The salient meaning is a stative one, in which case it's an adjective, cf. "Your room was very organised". On the other hand, it could have a dynamic meaning, in which case it's a past participle verb in a passive VP, cf. "Your room _was organised by the maid_".

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> "Well-rested" is a verb-centred compound adjective with the past participle **verb** "rested" as head. In "Your room was organised", "organised" is ambiguous. The salient meaning is a stative one, in which case it's an adjective, cf. "Your room was very organised". On the other hand, it could have a dynamic meaning, in which case it's a past participle verb in a passive VP, cf. "Your room *was organised by the maid*".